# What would Silicon-Based Aliens look like?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, science-fiction, xenobiology, races

Would silicon-based aliens' biochemistry cause them to look any different than the carbon-based humans that we have in the real world?  If so, what could they possibly look like?

For further clarification, these aliens are their world's equivalent to humans at least in that they are sapient, have the same intelligence level as us, and stand upright, although I have not yet set in stone what number of legs they have, nor what kinds of limbs they have for legs (e.g. human-like, arachnid-like, tentacles, etc.)

Comment: What do carbon-based lifeforms look like? Worms, jellyfish, humans, dinosaurs... which atom forms the primary structural component of macromolecules is just about the least significant contributor to the range of forms that creatures can take.

Comment: What specific biochemistry? And how is this question different from the other dozens of questions about silicon-based lifeforms? (And anyway, what common look do the carbon-based lifeforms on Earth have? What is the common look of a *Sequoia* tree, a slime mold, a colony of ascidians, a bee and a tiger?)

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley It doesn't have any noticeable effect on their appearance whatsoever?  Huh, I came into this thinking they'd at least possibly wind-up looking like rock-monsters or creatures made of glass.

Comment: @AlexP Which additional levels of specificity can I give their biochemistry to make the question easier to answer?  Will listing which substance their bodies use as a solvent be enough?  If not, which other components of their biochemistry should I list, as well?

Comment: The most important thing to is to make clear with what you are comparing them. That is, what is the meaning of the words "different than the carbon-based lifeforms". As far as I know, the carbon-based lifeforms we have here on Earth do not have any kind of common look. How is an oak tree similar to a jellyfish? Second, you need to specify the fundamental building blocks of the biochemistry. How do they obtain energy? What are their bodies made of? How do they store energy?

Comment: A blue whale, an Escherichia coli and a sequoia are all carbon based lifeforms, and they look nowhere like each other. What are you expecting for silicon based life?

Comment: @Jarren_Takar Diatoms (or at least their shells) actually *are* made of glass (amorphous silica), as are the cell walls of many plants, but those are carbon-based organisms. Meanwhile, you are *not* a graphite-monster or diamond-monster, despite also being built out of carbon. So why should silicon-based creatures look like rock or glass?

Comment: @AlexP & L.Dutch Ok, thanks for letting me know where I needed to clarify.  I'm mainly trying to figure-out what silicon-based life which was its' world's equivalent of humans.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Gotcha.  Thanks for letting me know.  I'll re-word the question accordingly.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: Could please give an example of plant with cell walls made of silica? It would be much appreciated. (All I know is that some grasses for example have a small amount of silica or organosilicon in their cell walls, but I know not of any plant where the cell walls are made mostly of a silicon-based material.)

Comment: @AlexP Good point there.

Comment: @AlexP I don't know of any examples where silica is the *primary* structural material (apart from diatoms, which aren't technically plants), but integration of amorphous silica into the primary cellulose structure occurs in a lot more than just grasses. See, e.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4828433/

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: Grasses were an example. But it is always a very few percent of the dry weight.

Comment: They would look like little green sandman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex silicon polymers generally fall into two classes: those that are inert in water, or those that are unstable in water.

The same applies to simpler silicon compounds: silica is almost entirely inert in water (it does dissolve as silicic acid, Si(OH)4, which makes it bioavailable... but only in very low concentrations, and no naturally-evolved terrestrial organism actually breaks the Si-O bonds to use it for anything more interesting than redepositing silica structurally); and silane, SiH4, rapidly hydrolyses.

So, simply by knowing that your aliens are silicon-based, we can immediately conclude that they do not use water, and they do not live in a similar temperature/pressure regime as we do on Earth. You won't be shaking hands with them without one or both of you being in a pretty hefty spacesuit!

Your aliens might well be extremely cryogenic, existing in liquid nitrogen and/or eutectic mixtures of organic solvents. Or slightly less cryogenic, relying on high-pressure anhydrous ammonia. Or somewhere between "uncomfortably warm" and "lethally hot", with bodily fluids based on fuming sulfuric acid.

Unfortunately, there's not much farther we can go from there. All of these fluids are transparent, so there's no barrier to fluid-filled eyes like we have--but also no barrier to pit-eyes or compound eyes. None of them are associated with atmospheres so dense or gravitational environments so different from ours as to significantly alter the mechanics of walking. None of them necessitate that large creatures be cold-blooded or warm-blooded. None of them would constrain the colors available through structural or chemical pigmentation. And similarly, this level of detail provides no *chemical* constraints on what the ecology in which your aliens evolved might look like, so you can't make inferences from that, either.

So, basically... they can look like whatever you want, as long as you can justify that appearance according to *other* constraints, common to all sorts of life.

Comment: Thanks for the info, man! :)

Answer (score 1):

They will either have one-or-more holes to take in food and excrete waste OR a way to absorb energy from light and absorb nutrients. They will have to obey a cube-square law for body size so they don’t overheat. Beyond that, assuming silicon is viable for life, silicon life will be as widely varying as carbon-based species.